# SourceTree terminal can't push, GUI can push

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

This question is exactly to the contrary of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388207/sourcetree-gui-cant-push-terminal-can-push)

I got this when pushing in the terminal:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master Pushing to ssh://xxxxx@git.mydomain.de/srv/git/MyFolder/MyProject.git

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I got no problems when pushing in GUI.

**I use ssh authentication.** A login panel pops up every 3 minutes after I close it and I'm not sure if it's normal.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the keys are loaded to the agent and if not, load them manually. This would just work fine with Sourcetree.

To check if key is loaded, use this command

```
ssh-add -l
```

To load keys, use this command

```
ssh-add <path_to_key>
```

e.g.,

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Additionally, please check if the account added in Preferences and remote URL used for clone match protocols (both are ssh).